# Problem with sending data from Python to PHP using POST

Tags: python, php

I am trying to send data from python to my localhost on rasberry pi but localhost doesn't want to display it. The server responds in python shell but it seems that php doesn't see the data.

python:

```
import requests
import time
        
while True:
    
    test = {"1": "4444", "1": "3333"}
    responde = requests.post('http://localhost/index.php', headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-forum-urlencoded'}, params = test)
    print(responde.url)
    print(responde.text)    
    time.sleep(10)
```

php(localhost):

```
While (True){       
    if (isset($_POST['1'])){
        $data = $_POST['1'];
        echo $data;
    }
    else{
        echo "no_data";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of wrapping everything in `While (True)` …?

Comment: If you send the data in `json` format, then decode the `json` data to manipulate it!

Comment: @BurhanKashour there is no JSON involved anywhere here, according to the code we have been shown.

Comment: You have a typo in the content type: `x-www-forum-` should be `x-www-form-`

Comment: I'm not a Python dev, but this: `{"1": "4444", "1": "3333"}` looks odd. Duplicate keys?

Comment: If `$_POST['1']` is set in your PHP code, it will keep echoing it over and over until you hit the "maximum memory" error (which is what happens when you create infinite loops like this in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loop in php code will hang your webserver. Please try removing while(true). Also due to this response is not returning to python code.

Also if requests are coming from different domain then you need to consider CORS as well.

Comment: Thanks man I will try it. I send data to localhost so no external server

Answer (score 0):

I have romoved the loop and exit at the end of php code. I think that the problem is with tagging the data that commes to the localhost.

python - no changes

php:

```
  if (isset($_POST['1'])){
        $data = $_POST['1'];
        echo $data;
    }
    else{
        echo "no_data";
    }
```